# Как узнать промежуточное значение линии в какой либо точке?

Tags: javascript, алгоритм, математика

Допустим у меня есть график "х". По горизонтали - это время:

начало newDateHour1 = 1520913600000;
конец newDateHour2 = 1520956800000;

есть "y" начало например: 0, конец 100

Проведем прямую линию [x,y] = начало [1520913600000, 0] конец [1520956800000, 100]

Как узнать промежуточное значение линии в какой либо точке? Например в точке текущего времени:

```
var new = new Date().getTime();

new = 1520922847845;
```

[image: График]

Comment: Попробуй использовать пропорцию. Т.е. 1520956800000 это 100, а 152092284785 это Y. Умножаешь 152092284785 на 100 и делишь на 1520956800000 должно получиться значение Y в этой точке X

Comment: Упустил тот факт, что начало координат по Х != 0. Скорей всего нужно будет из 1520956800000 отнять 152092284785. Это и будет значением Х в точке 100 по Y.

Answer (score 8):

Математика:

```js
function getCurrentY(yMin, yMax, xMin, xMax, xCurrent) {
  if (yMax < yMin) throw new Error('Ymax can not be less than Ymin');
  if (xMax < xMin) throw new Error('Xmax can not be less than Xmin');
  if (xMin > xCurrent || xMax < xCurrent) throw new Error('Xcurrent should be in range (Xmin, Xmax)');

  return (xCurrent - xMin) * (yMax - yMin) / (xMax - xMin) + yMin;
}

alert(getCurrentY(0, 100, 1520913600000, 1520956800000, 1520922847845));
```

Сама формула выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

где `y` - искомое значение

Answer (score 4):

Это называется линейная интерполяция, и применяется она примерно одинаково во многих языках программирования. Формула такая:

```
var fract = (x - X1) / (X2 - X1); // доля по оси X (0..1)
var y = Y1 + fract * (Y2 - Y1); // положение по оси Y
```

Давайте разбирать по шагам. Первая строчка - мы узнаем положение нужной точки на оси Х, *где* она находится в диапазоне между 1 и 2 точками. В примере ниже - она у нас на расстоянии 0,3 между `X1` и `X2`. Переходим ко второй строке. Чтобы узнать положение по оси Y, нам нужно взять положение `Y1` и прибавить к нему 0,3 расстояния между `Y1` и `Y2`. Итого, зная `X`, мы получаем `Y`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S.
Следите за тем, чтобы `X1` <> `X2`, иначе получите ошибку деления на 0.
Если `X1`, `X2` и/или `Y1`, `Y2` придут не по порядку, то отрицательные знаки поглотят друг друга и ничего страшного не случится.
Если `x` будет вне диапазона `X1`..`X2`, то у вас получится экстраполяция.

Comment: а разве не должно быть умножение на `(x2 - x1)` вместо `(y2 - y1)` и вместо `(x - x1)` `(y1 - y0)` ???

Comment: @ampawd дополнил вопрос картинкой